# ExtJS filter ComboBox dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have a property grid with multiple comboboxes and I want to filter the values in one box based on what is selected in the previous box.

My code looks like this:

```
var tempPropGrid = me.getView().add(
    {
        xtype:'propertygrid',
        width: 80,
        header: false,
        title: 'prop grid',
        //for some reason the headers are not hiding, we may need to deal with this using CSS
        //hideHeaders: true,
        enableColumnResize: false,
        sortableColumns: false,
        nameColumnWidth: 1,
        source: record.data,
        sourceConfig: {
            teamName: {
                editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                    store: teams,
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    displayField: 'teamName',
                    valueField: 'teamName'
                }),
                displayName: 'Team'
            },
            leadDev : {
                editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                    store: teamMembers.filter('teamName', teamName.value), // this probably won't work but you get the idea
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    displayField: 'personName',
                    valueField: 'personName'
                }),
                displayName: 'Lead Dev'
            },
```

and my JSON object looks like this:

```
{
                    "periodName": "Week1",
                    "teamName": "tango",
                    "roleName": "SWE III",
                    "roleExperience": "3",
                    "id": "21ea7f61-a9a5-4dbd-b405-e7a0449f8096"
                },
```

So essentially I am assigning a project to a team, and then based on which team I choose I want to select a leadDev based on them being in that team.

I am not sure how to pluck the value of a combo box and apply a filter dynamically so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in the grid is a model. So, in your `leadDev` combobox you just need to listen for `'expand'` event, then retrieve current row model and apply value from this model to the filter. 
It should look like this(not checked):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                store: store
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'personName',
                valueField: 'personName',
                listeners: {
                    'expand' : function(combo) {
                         var grid = combo.up('grid');
                         var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                         var currentRowModel = //get this from selection
                         combo.getStore().clearFilter(true);
                         combo.getStore().filter('teamName',currentRowModel.teamName);
                     }
                }
            })
```

And you need to update current model when user selects value from the first combobox